# Get indexes for first occurrence of each element in a list?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of about 90k elements (about 670 unique). I would like to get the indexes for the first occurrence of each value. I have just tried a list comprehension like this:

```
In: [["foo", "bar", "baz", "bar", "foo"].index(x) for x in ["foo", "bar", "baz", "bar", "foo"]]
Out: [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
```

This works, but it takes a couple of minutes to run on my machine. What is a better (faster) way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking to enumerate the items in the list? If so, use `enumerate(["foo", "bar", "baz", "bar", "foo"])`.

Comment: I'm not looking to enumerate the list, I'm looking to get just the index of the first occurrence. I'm going to fix my question.

Comment: Do you want the output to be `[0, 1, 2, 1, 0]` or without duplicates?

Comment: I wan the output to be `[0, 1, 2, 1, 0]`

Comment: @NathanMiller In that case I think that your current approach is the likely the fastest way. A couple of minutes does not seem that long to wait.

Comment: @Ev. Kounis' answer (below) is similar to mine, but runs in a fraction of the time.

Comment: @NathanMiller The point is to understand why though. You are asking python to tell you what the index of the same item is thousands of times; again and again. In your simplistic example above for instance, you are asking for `bar` and `foo` twice. Now if `bar` appeared not twice but say 5000 times, this would be time wasted..

Comment: @Ev.Kounis solution doesn't give `[0, 1, 2, 1, 0]`, the output you claimed you wanted though. You'd save us all some time you were clearer with your question.

Comment: @Chris_Rands, you're right. I should not have accepted that answer. I just realized it doesn't do what I expected it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to use `enumerate` (unless you want the first occurrence of each item in the list):

```
strings = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "bar", "foo"]
for index, value in enumerate(strings):
    print index, value
```

outputs

```
0 foo
1 bar
2 baz
3 bar
4 foo
```

If you wanted, for example, `1 bar` instead of `3 bar`, you can maintain a dictionary of found strings:

```
for index, value in enumerate(strings):
    if value not in d:
        d[value] = index

for value in strings:
    print value, d[value]
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands, I do actually want the first occurrence (my question/ title where poorly written before)

Comment: this works fine for the example posted by OP but does not perform as well for the list with 90k elements and 600 unique values.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Some things just take time. There's not much you can do to improve on comparing hashed values to identify duplicates in a set.

Answer (score 3):

You can build a dictionary that stores the index of the first occurrence of each word. 
That way, you only look through your big list once, and the dictionary lookups are much faster, since the dictionary contains each value only once, and is accessed in O(log(n)).

```
l = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "bar", "foo"]
v = {}
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    if x not in v:
        v[x] = i

# v is now {'bar': 1, 'baz': 2, 'foo': 0}
```

Also, if you want to output a 90k-long list containing the index of the first occurrence for each element in the original list, you can get it that way:

```
output = [v[x] for x in l]
# output is now [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very ambiguous but as i understood it you have many duplicate values and you just want to get the index of the first appearance for each. I would leverage sets like this:

```
my_list = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "bar", "foo"]

my_list_unique = set(my_list)
indexes = [(x, my_list.index(x)) for x in my_list_unique]
print(indexes)  # prints -> [('foo', 0), ('bar', 1), ('baz', 2)]
```

Note that the creation of a set in line 3 removes the duplicates so every entry in  `my_list_unique` only exists once. This saves time when looking for the indexes. As far as the results go, it is a list of tuples where each tuple contains the string and the index in which it is first found in `my_list`

Comment: won't the list comprehension in line 4 make you iterate through the 90k-long list about 670 times?

Comment: The big list is 90k long and the list comprehension in line 4 iterates over `my_list_unique` which is just 670 items.

Comment: yes, but `my_list.index()` also has to iterate through `my_list`... Only up to the first occurrence of the current `x`, but still, it's not negligible.

Comment: @maahl I doubt that the `index()` method is implemented like that but i am sure that it is as fast as it can be..

Comment: just for future reference: it seems it is implemented like that :) https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/listobject.c#l2296