# Finding indices of first non-zero items in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following list :

```
list_test = [0,0,0,1,0,2,5,4,0,0,5,5,3,0,0]
```

I would like to find the indices of all the first numbers in the list that are not equal to zero.

In this case the output should be:

```
output = [3,5,10]
```

Is there a Pythonic way to do this?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638003/get-indexes-for-first-occurrence-of-each-element-in-a-list) has similar problem to yours. Just drop '0' after.

Comment: Are you sure this is the right output?

Comment: the list has more positive items than 3, why the output has only 3 ?

Comment: I want only the first index of numbers that are > than 0 (non-zero)

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko Output contains only the first index of a group of non zero values.

Comment: not following, there are 5 distinct numbers higher than 0, why the size of expected out is 3 ?

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko sequentially we want to flag only the first nonzero indices, in this case the numbers flagged will be 1,2 and 5

Comment: why indexes 6, 7,11,12 not added to the output list ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the output, I think you want the first index of continuous non-zero sequences.

As for **Pythonic**, I understand it as **list generator**, while it's **poorly readable**.

```
# works with starting with non-zero element.
# list_test = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 5, 4, 0, 0, 5, 5, 3, 0, 0]
list_test = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 5, 4, 0, 0, 5, 5, 3, 0, 0]
output = [i for i in range(len(list_test)) if list_test[i] != 0 and (i == 0 or list_test[i - 1] == 0)]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a `numpy` based solution:

```
import numpy as np
l = np.array([0,0,0,1,0,2,5,4,0,0,5,5,3,0,0])
non_zeros = np.where(l != 0)[0]
diff = np.diff(non_zeros)
np.append(non_zeros [0], non_zeros [1 + np.where(diff>=2)[0]])  # array([ 3,  5, 10], dtype=int64)
```

Explanation:

First, we find the non-zero places, then we calculate the pair differences of those position (we need to add 1 because its `out[i] = a[i+1] - a[i]`, read more about [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)) then we need to add the first element of non-zero and also all the values where the difference was greater then 1)

Note:

It will also work for the case where the array start with non-zero element or all non-zeros.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40638003/get-indexes-for-first-occurrence-of-each-element-in-a-list).

```
l = [0,0,0,1,0,2,5,4,0,0,5,5,3,0,0]
v = {}
for i, x in enumerate(l):
    if x != 0 and x not in v:
        v[x] = i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_test = [0,0,0,1,0,2,5,4,0,0,5,5,3,0,0]
res = {}
for index, item in enumerate(list_test):
    if item > 0:
        res.setdefault(index, None)
print(res.keys())
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't knwo what you mean by Pythonic way, but this is an answer using a simple loop:

```
list_test = [0,0,0,1,0,2,5,4,0,0,5,5,3,0,0]

out = []

if list_test[0] == 0:
    out.append(0)

for i in range(1, len(list_test)):
    if (list_test[i-1] == 0) and (list_test[i] != 0):
        out.append(i)
```

Don't hesitate to precise what you mean by "Pythonic" !

Comment: What happens when the first item is not zero?